# How to delete a directory that contains other subdirectories and files on Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, directory

I have a directory that contains files and other directories. I need to delete then all in one command, but without asking me for each file if I'm sure that i want to delete i; there is any command for this?

Comment: You can use `/bin/rm -rf folder`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to delete that folder recursively,

```
rm -r folder-name
```

From `rm --help`,

```
-r, -R, --recursive   remove directories and their contents recursively
```

Comment: sudo allows you to delete a folder which was owned by the root.

Comment: This is potentially dangerous, and may accidentally clobber stuff; `sudo` is not required most of the time, and neither is `-f`, since without it, `rm` asks for you confirmation on files you may not want to delete (like, this without writeable bit, or immutable flag). Only use either when it's needed.

Comment: Root files were not mentioned by the OP.

Comment: rm -rf folderName removed all the subfolders and the files

Answer (score 1):

```
rm -rf <directory_name>
```

This command forcefully(-f) removes all directories and files under the provided directory name.

For more verbose output:
Use `rm -rfv <directory_name>`

Comment: +1 one for calling directories "directories", since Unix has no "folders", which sounds like weird Microsoft talk. That's why it's `mkdir` and `chdir` and `rmdir` and such down at the syscall level. There are no "folders" in the Unix API.